# Multiple redirect issue in XPM

Tags: experience-manager

I am getting a multile redirect error in XPM for DCP. The issue is happening only in this particular scenerio .We have a section on website where all pages are DCP enabled. All the pages are served by this single page `test.aspx`.
The URL of the destination page(physical path) is `path/test.aspx?obj1={param1}&obj2={param2}` and virtual url is `path/param1/param2`  (SEO friendly).

When I hit the virtual url on my browser, I am able to see the page loaded. This virtual url redirects to destination url internally. This page is XPM enabled also as I can see the [SDL Tridion] button in left corner of my screen.

Now when I hit the [SDL Tridion] button in left corner and I start editing the DCP Component enabled for XPM. After saving it when I hit update preview my Page crashes and one message pops up:

> "There were too many redirects."

I have put fidller in between and I can see it is trying to redirect. Request and response is as below from fidller .

**Request**

GET ***/path/2212728/dcp-xpm-testing HTTP/1.1

**Response**

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: ***/path/2212728/dcp-xpm-testing
Date: Mon, 15 Jun 2015 12:16:52 GMT
Content-Length: 171

Object moved

### Object moved to [here](/***/path/2212728/dcp-xpm-testing).

We have done this redirection to support SEO friendly redirection. I think while loading it from session preview database Tridion is doing something strange as the physical page is not present on content delivery server.